# SVG editors, or: SVG vs. JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg

I'd like to create SVG charts from a database app. However, I know nothing about creating SVG, so I'd like to start with an editor, if I can find one. This should ideally let me -

1 - place a zoom control in the image

2 - place a pan control in the image

3 - do various things on mouseovers - pop up a data box, highlight chart points

4 - create scatter and time-line charts from my own dataset, with legends, axes, and so on.

The idea is that, once I get a basic template from the editor, I can write C code to directly generate the SVG code.

I've spent hours looking, and I can't find any commercial or free apps that can do anything like this. "SVG editors" primarily draw circles and rectangles, which isn't much use to me. Have I missed something? It seems that SVG editor development stopped several years ago, and various editors have been discontinued. I can't even find example SVG code that does anything similar to this.

In fact, the more I read the more it seems that I need to do this in JavaScript, rather than directly creating images (but I don't know JavaScript either). Any thoughts on which way I should go? I've looked at maybe 20 javascript libs that will do charting, but none of them seem to tick all of 1 to 3 above. I also need to overlay polylines on scatter plots, and few of them will do that. Google charts is close, but it won't do the last one.

Oh, I've got a captive audience, and they'll upgrade their browsers if I ask nicely.

Thanks -

Al

Answer (score 1):

The [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) program is an SVG editor. It also allows you to [attach javascript](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SVG_with_javascript) to elements of it. It doesn't actually show you the effects, however. But if you then load it into a modern browser you can see the interactive effects. You do have have to know Javascript, but it mainly involves adding handlers and adjusting the CSS properties or changing attributes.

Comment: I haven't tried Inkscape, but I did spend maybe half an hour with the docs.  As far as I can make out, it's basically just an illustration package. I need something smart enough to embed zoom and pan/scroll widgets in the generated SVG, and some management of mouse events.If I'm going to mebed Javascript in it I might just as well bite the bullet and do the whole thing in Javascript, using one of the 20 or 30 Javascript chart libs out there.

Comment: I had a look at gRaphael, which is specialised for charting (and maybe 20 other Javascript libs). The demo's poor, so I don't think I'll look at it in detail. Of the Javascript libs, Highcharts is probably the one that comes over best from a look at the website.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google charts will do the last ones:

Annotated Time Line: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line

Scatter: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#scatter_chart

Comment: It's great for time lines, but it can't overlay lines on the scatter plots, so they're not much use. Apparently it's possible to create new visualizations, but I can't find any documentation on how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, haven't worked out commenting yet, so the 2 above are a bit abrupt - CR did an 'add comment'?!

Comment: Would this Combo Chart get you what you're looking for? http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#combo_chart

Comment: Unfortunately, the combo only combines bars, lines, and area lines. I need to combine scatter and lines. I asked on the mailing list a couple of days ago and someone from Google said they couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to write C to generate the SVG code, then you can make it write EMCAScript within the SVG itself for panning, zooming and various mouseover effects. I've written a description of how to add a pan and zoom control at: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/pan-and-zoom-control